# How to sort WooCommerce product by featured or tag without additional plugins?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sql-order-by, wordpress-featured-image

I'm using shortcode to list a product category like this

```
[product_category category="products" orderby="title" order="asc"]
```

And wonder how can I make featured products be on the top on the list? It has something to do with [orderby parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters), but I have no idea.

*Please do not propose 3rd party plugins.*
More info in WooCommerce official [docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/).

Comment: You want a shortcode or `WP_Query` will also do?

Comment: I prefer shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

> Product has a custom field as `_featured` which is set as **`yes`**
>   for featured product and **`no`** for non-featured product. So you can
>   use [`woocommerce_shortcode_products_query`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-22) filter to overwrite
>   WooCOmmerce shortcode.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'wh_woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby');

function wh_woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby($args)
{

    $standard_array = ['menu_order', 'title', 'date', 'rand', 'id'];
//  print_r($args['orderby']);
    if (isset($args['orderby']) && !in_array($args['orderby'], $standard_array))
    {
        $args['meta_key'] = '_featured';
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
    }
//  print_r($args);
    return $args;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

**USAGE**
To list product form featured to non-featured (i.e., form `yes` to `no`)

```
[product_category category="products" orderby="_featured" order="DESC"]
```

Please Note:: *above code seems to be working, but if you print `$args['orderby']` it is not showing `_featured` key, so I hardcoded, it in the `$args`. It is not an standard way*.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like that doest have an effect. They are just sorted from Z to A.

Comment: I have updated my answer, it seems to be working, but I'll again revised my answer soon. till that time you can use this.

Comment: Now it looks like they are sorted randomly with every refresh.